# R - Remove terms that appear more than once in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, words

I'm looking to discover methods of improving the effectiveness of LDA topic modeling on short text documents (Tweets) using R. On a hunch, I'd like to remove generic words that don't really allude to any particular topic, which tend to appear in multiple topics.

I have a matrix with 10 columns and 50 rows, like so:

```
      Topic 1    Topic 2     Topic 3      Topic 4     Topic 5    Topic 6      Topic 7     Topic 8     Topic 9     
 [1,] "just"     "much"      "like"       "know"      "just"     "will"       "people"    "still"     "even"      
 [2,] "like"     "good"      "much"       "love"      "make"     "call"       "need"      "time"      "just"      
 [3,] "good"     "shit"      "good"       "back"      "time"     "like"       "just"      "love"      "tell"      
 [4,] "make"     "come"      "think"      "come"      "life"     "much"       "much"      "want"      "make"      
 [5,] "play"     "fuck"      "want"       "good"      "take"     "want"       "like"      "real"      "real"      
 [6,] "think"    "real"      "thank"      "ever"      "people"   "ever"       "think"     "life"      "good"      
 [7,] "right"    "even"      "find"       "night"     "start"    "love"       "know"      "make"      "think"     
 [8,] "fuck"     "make"      "little"     "every"     "work"     "feel"       "real"      "tell"      "hello"     
 [9,] "need"     "look"      "love"       "will"      "much"     "hello"      "time"      "will"      "know"      
[10,] "love"     "like"      "feel"       "keep"      "wish"     "happy"      "love"      "just"      "need"      
[11,] "every"    "friend"    "watch"      "take"      "week"     "never"      "year"      "hard"      "look"      
[12,] "gonna"    "thank"     "hate"       "tell"      "back"     "work"       "shit"      "fuck"      "want"      
[13,] "hard"     "talk"      "actual"     "sleep"     "think"    "real"       "wanna"     "today"     "friend"    
[14,] "girl"     "wanna"     "game"       "first"     "love"     "stop"       "good"      "live"      "keep"      
[15,] "game"     "want"      "change"     "actual"    "live"     "start"      "play"      "back"      "always"    
[16,] "life"     "think"     "everything" "work"      "right"    "last"       "look"      "take"      "thank"     
[17,] "come"     "will"      "year"       "today"     "night"    "friend"     "hello"     "watch"     "ain"       
[18,] "will"     "feel"      "shit"       "wait"      "many"     "nigga"      "give"      "good"      "like"      
[19,] "friend"   "just"      "someone"    "real"      "okay"     "today"      "feel"      "think"     "much"      
[20,] "bitch"    "girl"      "back"       "great"     "talk"     "think"      "back"      "stop"      "okay"      
[21,] "sure"     "always"    "something"  "something" "will"     "hope"       "take"      "year"      "right"     
[22,] "miss"     "miss"      "mean"       "watch"     "year"     "come"       "also"      "right"     "feel"      
[23,] "never"    "something" "many"       "shit"      "last"     "mind"       "follow"    "great"     "show"      
[24,] "also"     "first"     "make"       "please"    "fuck"     "okay"       "wait"      "feel"      "mean"      
[25,] "someone"  "tweet"     "take"       "much"      "show"     "make"       "girl"      "look"      "never"     
[26,] "wanna"    "many"      "everyone"   "wish"      "never"    "leave"      "never"     "always"    "leave"     
[27,] "wait"     "someone"   "also"       "always"    "know"     "hour"       "something" "hate"      "someone"   
[28,] "people"   "find"      "lose"       "never"     "good"     "people"     "talk"      "like"      "miss"      
[29,] "always"   "take"      "sleep"      "leave"     "today"    "hear"       "hard"      "never"     "happy"     
[30,] "feel"     "tell"      "hello"      "follow"    "please"   "right"      "still"     "sleep"     "nigga"     
[31,] "call"     "know"      "friend"     "show"      "look"     "lmao"       "hear"      "know"      "start"     
[32,] "look"     "happy"     "last"       "gonna"     "gonna"    "someone"    "miss"      "happy"     "last"      
[33,] "live"     "still"     "will"       "everyone"  "shit"     "keep"       "money"     "play"      "people"    
[34,] "ever"     "watch"     "life"       "hello"     "thank"    "tweet"      "actual"    "thank"     "wait"      
[35,] "give"     "hear"      "show"       "thank"     "even"     "everything" "mind"      "work"      "money"     
[36,] "tweet"    "life"      "still"      "lmao"      "hello"    "look"       "happen"    "someone"   "shit"      
[37,] "everyone" "sleep"     "call"       "want"      "feel"     "take"       "start"     "friend"    "still"     
[38,] "mind"     "little"    "hour"       "last"      "real"     "first"      "show"      "little"    "back"      
[39,] "real"     "never"     "ain"        "like"      "someone"  "little"     "always"    "gonna"     "gonna"     
[40,] "hope"     "leave"     "wish"       "okay"      "ain"      "game"       "right"     "hello"     "come"      
[41,] "lmao"     "please"    "work"       "happy"     "tweet"    "money"      "want"      "change"    "work"      
[42,] "happen"   "wait"      "right"      "girl"      "happen"   "show"       "bitch"     "also"      "everything"
[43,] "time"     "hello"     "need"       "think"     "hour"     "hate"       "tell"      "wait"      "give"      
[44,] "please"   "great"     "real"       "even"      "anything" "follow"     "hate"      "find"      "lmao"      
[45,] "still"    "nigga"     "hard"       "hate"      "always"   "live"       "gonna"     "hope"      "time"      
[46,] "week"     "hope"      "great"      "talk"      "bitch"    "always"     "change"    "talk"      "talk"      
[47,] "lose"     "hate"      "people"     "ain"       "mind"     "great"      "nigga"     "night"     "mind"      
[48,] "find"     "bitch"     "look"       "someone"   "girl"     "just"       "many"      "week"      "hour"      
[49,] "take"     "wish"      "always"     "many"      "stop"     "time"       "sure"      "something" "little"    
[50,] "hour"     "work"      "fuck"       "live"      "leave"    "night"      "watch"     "lmao"      "lose"      
      Topic 10  
 [1,] "know"    
 [2,] "time"    
 [3,] "will"    
 [4,] "hello"   
 [5,] "make"    
 [6,] "people"  
 [7,] "mean"    
 [8,] "year"    
 [9,] "need"    
[10,] "anything"
[11,] "want"    
[12,] "every"   
[13,] "love"    
[14,] "life"    
[15,] "good"    
[16,] "fuck"    
[17,] "stop"    
[18,] "gonna"   
[19,] "happen"  
[20,] "follow"  
[21,] "game"    
[22,] "nigga"   
[23,] "sure"    
[24,] "tweet"   
[25,] "great"   
[26,] "real"    
[27,] "show"    
[28,] "hope"    
[29,] "always"  
[30,] "miss"    
[31,] "money"   
[32,] "ain"     
[33,] "lose"    
[34,] "bitch"   
[35,] "tell"    
[36,] "keep"    
[37,] "call"    
[38,] "right"   
[39,] "take"    
[40,] "much"    
[41,] "never"   
[42,] "like"    
[43,] "shit"    
[44,] "sleep"   
[45,] "leave"   
[46,] "lmao"    
[47,] "everyone"
[48,] "play"    
[49,] "look"    
[50,] "watch"
```

I'd like to remove all terms that are listed in multiple columns from every column that they appear in. Each topic can contain an uneven number of key words.

P.S.: Any other related insights on using LDA on short text using R would be appreciated as well.

Comment: So if a word appears in more than one column it should be removed?

Comment: @42 Yes, altogether

Comment: So you may potentially produce a ragged (by column) matrix?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton The result does not need to be in matrix format. Just something that can generally be worked with.

Comment: As far as I can tell every single value in the first column (and I haven't looked at the other) would be removed. Is that really going to deliver what you expect?

Comment: @42 I can try just adding more terms until it does

Comment: In the example, you offer EVERY SINGLE TERM is present at least 3 times! The specific answer to your request is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove words appearing in more than one column == keep words that appear in only a singular column, relative to the other columns.

For each column, Take setdiff of column X, relative to all columns except X:

```
lapply(1:ncol(df),function(ix){
  a = as.character(df[,ix])
  b = as.character(unlist(df[,-ix,drop=F]))
  setdiff(a,b)
})
```

This produces list of lists.

This will include words that appear more than once in one column, and zero times in all other columns. If it needs to be unique, then some additional work is needed.

As has been stated in the above comments, at present, this yields an empty list for the matrix of words provided in the question.